# IOS app to display values via BLE from an ESP32

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

I have an ESP32 Battery monitor system (BMS) whose status I want to view on an iPhone, there are about 100 values to be monitored with a maximum update rate of once per second. I also needs to be able to send settings to the BMS occasionally.

Blynk seemed to be the perfect app to do this but the new version 2.0 doesn't support BLE! Does anyone know a similar app that could do this?

Comment: why not use WiFi?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the ESP32 up as a web server and creating an API based on the values? Using this instead of bluetooth allows you to view the values from anywhere with internet connection, and is easier to implement and use across different platforms

You can do this by implementing code into the ESP32, so that when you make http requests, it returns with a value, just like any other API would. Then in Xcode where you are building your IOS app you can make http requests to the web server and retrieve values

for example, in the ESP32 you can do something like this (assuming you are using the Arduino IDE to program it):

```
server.on("/value", [](AsyncWebServerRequest * request))
{
    String value = "value"
    request->send(200,"text/plain", value)
}
```

This YouTube video shows you this in more detail: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cWZP7Y8qP6E

Then, in Xcode you can implement something along the lines of:

```
func loadData() async {
    guard let url = URL(string: "http://IP-address-of-esp32/path-of-value", ) else {
        print("Invalid URL")
        return
    }

    do {
        let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
        // process data here with the 'data' variable
    } catch {
        print("Invalid Data")
    }
}

//Be aware that this is asynchronous when calling it
```

This person also explains it in more detail in a YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBCX1atOvdA

Now, since you have a web server and API set up on your ESP32, and a method of retrieving the values in your IOS app, you can go on and use the values to build the app to your liking.

Good Luck!

Comment: Sorry for not really mentioning any app or method using BLE to solve this, since I am not sure how I would do it myself, however I hope my reply has helped you maybe see a different way of approaching your problem without using BLE